# In Flex, how can I remove a component from the tab order?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, navigation

In Flex [4], when cycling the focus through components by pressing Tab, how can I remove particular components (eg. some buttons) from the tab cycle. I want those buttons to be skipped completely when pressing Tab.

Thanks

Comment: Did u set the tabindex for the each components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `tabFocusEnabled` property to `false`.